# Createjs and Firefox 72

Tags: firefox, createjs

After updating Firefox (Firefox 72.0) an error appeared: "The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains invalid content which cannot be decoded successfully." Apps don't work, because of this problem with audio playback. Has anyone encountered such a problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got the exact same problem but here's a bit more info for anyone working on a solution. The latest updates of firefox work fine on IOS and Android, the problem is on windows 10. Here are a couple of educational resources that several of our school's reported as broken by the recent update (they work fine in chrome, safari and edge):

https://www.echalk.co.uk/Science/physics/spacecadet/SpaceCadet.htm

https://www.echalk.co.uk/ComputerScience/ComputerSystems/Memory/Moonlander/memoryMoonlander.html

For comparison, here is a rource that still works in Firefox:

https://www.echalk.co.uk/Maths/estimation/fractions/estimationFractions.html

All resource were built using the same libraries, notably createJS.